# If cell value B2 does not match any value in Column A on Sheet2, copy the row to Sheet 3 (without script)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an outdated table of registered members and a second up to date table (which is actually only a list with member numbers).
I need to check the old table for members who left and put these (who left) to a new table.

So basically:

- if B2 != any value in column A(on Sheet2) copy row 2 (from Sheet1) to A2(Sheet3);
- if B3 != any value in column A(on Sheet2) copy row 3 (from Sheet1) to the next free row on A(Sheet3);

Alternatively, deleting rows on the first table and skipping the creation of Sheet3 is possible as well.

I mustn't use scripts, so I hope there is a function only solution possible.

If it helps, Sheet2 is variable, I can put the values from column A to Column B (or any other).

I tried `=search`, `=if`, `=not`, `=vlookup` and even failed more horribly on `=query`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75022032/edit) your question and insert two [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if B2 != any value in column A(on Sheet2) copy row 2 (from Sheet1) to A2(Sheet3)

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A2:C, isna(match(Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet2!A2:A, 0)))
```

Comment: it returns a parsing error. I added a publicly editable sample spreadsheet.

Comment: I've tried this in the sample I made and it works, but it doesn't work in the actual spreadsheet I need to work with. Strange..

Comment: In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators. In other words, replace all the commas in the formula with semicolons.